# Generalising sqlalchemy query gives "Please use the .select_from() method... providing an explicit ON clause... ambiguity"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have models that follow this pattern (a main model and an item model associated with it):

```
class modelA(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  items = db.relationship('modelA_Item', backref='model_a', lazy='dynamic')
  total = db.Column(db.Integer())

class modelA_Item(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  model_a_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('model_a.id'))
  category = db.Column(db.String(20))

class modelB(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  items = db.relationship('modelB_Item', backref='model_b', lazy='dynamic')
  total = db.Column(db.Integer())

class modelB_Item(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  model_b_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('model_b.id'))
  category = db.Column(db.String(20))

...and more such model pairs
```

If I construct a query as follows:

```
item_model_alias = aliased(modelA_Item)
subquery = select(modelA.total).join(item_model_alias).filter(item_model_alias.category == 'Cat1').group_by(modelA.id)
result = db.session.query(func.sum(subquery.c.total)).first()[0]
```

I get the correct result. I tried to create a generic code so that I don't have to write query for each model pair.

```
model = modelA #for example
item_model = model.items.property.mapper.class_
item_model_alias = aliased(item_model)
subquery = select(model.total).join(item_model_alias).filter(item_model_alias.category=='Cat1').group_by(model.id)
result = db.session.query(func.sum(subquery.c.total)).first()[0]
```

I get the error:

> raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError( sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:
> Don't know how to join to <AliasedInsp at 0x10b5bba00;
> modelA_Item(modelA_Item)>. Please use the .select_from() method to
> establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON
> clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.

Why is generalising causing this error?
Interestingly, it works correctly if in the generalised code, I add a select_from method as follows:

```
subquery = select(model.total).select_from(model).join(item_model_alias).filter(item_model_alias.category=='Cat1').group_by(model.id)
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: type object 'modelA_Item' has no attribute 'total'` for the `select` in the "generic" code.

Comment: Oh my bad. Have edited the query now to use model.total instead of item_model.

Comment: Now it works without error ...